# getting "Access is denied" trying to run a py2exe setup file in command prompt

Tags: python, cmd, py2exe

So I wrote a program, but wanted to make it an executable file and have been following the instructions for using py2exe however when i type in cmd

```
<H:\Documents\Python Programs\example>python setup.py py2exe
```

It returns 'Access is denied'

I have tried running as administrator and making sure that the python folder is a path in system environment variables (via control panel) but apart from that I am not sure what else there is. Any ideas?

Edit: Forgot to mention I don't have any antivirus programs and i tried turning windows firewall off as well.

Edit 2: Below is my setup.py and I have tested that my program does work

```python
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['example.py'])
```

Comment: Can you show the content of your `setup.py` please? And is your program working when you execute it with the default python interpreter from the same folder?

Comment: `Access is denied` to what?

Comment: it simply returns 'Access is denied', i tried just accessing each folder along the path and had no troubles, its only when i type in setup.py

the file is not open when i try it